# C# The variable name '@Occurrence_Time' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I am working on C# .net. I am using Visual Studio 2015 referring to the question I am facing that exception.

This is my SQL query:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Device_Events (Device_ID, Event_ID, Occurrence_Time, Recovery_Time) values (@Device_ID , @Event_ID, @Occurrence_Time, @Recovery_Time)", con);
```

and this is my C# code:

```
 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_ID", device_Id);
 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event_ID", event_Id);

 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence_1, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time_1))
 {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery_1, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time_1))
     {
         cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time_1;
         cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Recovery_Time_1;
     }
 }

 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence_2, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time_2))
 {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery_2, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time_2))
     {
         cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time_2;
         cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Recovery_Time_2;
     }
 }

 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence_3, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time_3))
 {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery_3, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time_3))
     {
         cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time_3;
         cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Recovery_Time_3;
     }
 }

 int Device_Events_rows_executed = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The exception is raised on the line `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

I know the reason why the exception is happening, but I want to know the solution for it. I am getting this data from a meter and 3 events are generated by it, so I want to insert them into same table

I don't want to use a stored procedure.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: use cmd2.Parameters.clear() before assign

Comment: Your `if` statements are not separated by `else`. Apparently more than one of the expressions in those statements is `true` and the parameters are added more than once.

Comment: @heijp06 it should be like this as already told in the question i have 3 events coming from meter so i have to insert them into same table

Comment: @SandipPatel at which point should i use  `cmd2.Parameters.Clear()`? Because when i placed it inside my conditions it gives me exception `Must declare the scalar variable "@Device_ID".`

Comment: You if else if else if

Comment: @viveknuna can't use it because all the 3 events are coming at the same time so these all 3 events must be inserted

Comment: then insert three rows or add more columns or change datatype of columns from DateTime to varchar and insert all values as comma separated value

Comment: In that case, call `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery` for each successfully parsed row.